# is it possible to use c++ library with postgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Currently, I working with PostgreSQL code. I want to add a feature with Postgres as part of my project. But I want to know "is it possible to add C++ library with Postgres?", so I able to use some functions from that library.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#EXTEND-CPP) says:

> Although the PostgreSQL backend is written in C, it is possible to write extensions in C++ if these guidelines are followed:
>
> - All functions accessed by the backend must present a C interface to the backend; these C functions can then call C++ functions. For example, extern C linkage is required for backend-accessed functions. This is also necessary for any functions that are passed as pointers between the backend and C++ code.
> - Free memory using the appropriate deallocation method. For example, most backend memory is allocated using `palloc()`, so use `pfree()` to free it. Using C++ delete in such cases will fail.
> - Prevent exceptions from propagating into the C code (use a catch-all block at the top level of all `extern` C functions). This is necessary even if the C++ code does not explicitly throw any exceptions, because events like out-of-memory can still throw exceptions. Any exceptions must be caught and appropriate errors passed back to the C interface. If possible, compile C++ with `-fno-exceptions` to eliminate exceptions entirely; in such cases, you must check for failures in your C++ code, e.g. check for NULL returned by `new()`.
> - If calling backend functions from C++ code, be sure that the C++ call stack contains only plain old data structures (POD). This is necessary because backend errors generate a distant `longjmp()` that does not properly unroll a C++ call stack with non-POD objects.
>
> In summary, it is best to place C++ code behind a wall of `extern` C functions that interface to the backend, and avoid exception, memory, and call stack leakage.